# Inheritant entities: update model from DB having

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an EF model which has some entities inheritance.
When I tried to "update model from DB", my model updated, but I got new warning:
"The association between the types in the model was excluded because it had a referential constraint which referenced properties which could not be found in those types."

As far as I understood, the reason is that inheritor entites does not have primary key defined in model. But tables in database has primary keys in tables. Is there any common way to resolve the issue but keep inheritance?
I tried to define the same "Id" column at these entities but got a conflict with parent table "Id" column.